# How to build a WHERE-clause in a LiquiBase changeset

Tags: where-clause, liquibase, changeset

How do I have to define a changeset in 'LiquiBase' notation for updating a table column whith an AND-ed WHERE-clause:

```
<changeSet id="ddl update tables : modify datatype for MY_TABLE.STATE_ABBREV" author="xxx">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN" onFailMessage="Column MY_TABLE.STATE_ABBREV doesn't exists.">
        <and>
            <tableExists tableName="MY_TABLE"/>
            <columnExists tableName="MY_TABLE" columnName="STATE_ABBREV"/>
        </and>
    </preConditions>
    <update tableName="MY_TABLE">
        <column name="STATE_ABBREV" value="AS"/>
        <where>AGU   /***AND STATE_ID=3***/  ??????????????????
        </where>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you put in the `<where>` tag is simply appended to the end of the UPDATE statement after a " WHERE ". You can put anything in the where tag that you would normally put in SQL.

Example:

```
<changeSet id="ddl update tables : modify datatype for MY_TABLE.STATE_ABBREV" author="xxx">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN" onFailMessage="Column MY_TABLE.STATE_ABBREV doesn't exists.">
        <and>
            <tableExists tableName="MY_TABLE"/>
            <columnExists tableName="MY_TABLE" columnName="STATE_ABBREV"/>
        </and>
    </preConditions>
    <update tableName="MY_TABLE">
        <column name="STATE_ABBREV" value="AS"/>
        <where>STATE_ABBREV IS NULL AND STATE_ID=3</where>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: As you can see in the code in my question this was my assumption but I thought there would be a 'better'/a liquiBase way to do by using something like <and>/<or>; or <whereparams>.

Comment: I would suggest just sticking to the <where> block. You can specify You can specify a <whereParam> block with nested <param name="STATE_ID" valueNumeric="3"> tags, but you still need to specify the <where> block with ":STATE_ID=:value" placeholders that are then filled in from value in the <params>. The <param> tags are mainly helpful in handling differences in boolean values across database types.