# LiquiBase changeset: how do build a where clause based on ANOTHER table's column

Tags: where-clause, liquibase, changeset

Building upon the question [How to build a WHERE-clause in a LiquiBase changeset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063998/how-to-build-a-where-clause-in-a-liquibase-changeset), I would like to choose the default value of a column based on the value of **a column from a different table**.

For instance, I have two tables, *order* and *order_history*. Pls note that we maintain all our orders in both *order* in *order_history* as well. Once an order is completed, it is removed from *order* table.

*order* has a column 'status' but we missed it on *order_history*, you can call it a bad design.
How do I add 'status' to *order_history* now, and copy the value from the corresponding order
in *order* table for existing data at the time of upgrade? Is there a way to do this in liquibase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `order` and `order_history` are connected with the foreign key, then you can just do the following:

```
<changeSet id="foo" author="bar">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <and>
            <columnExists tableName="order" columnName="status"/>
            <columnExists tableName="order_history" columnName="status"/>
        </and>
    </preConditions>
    <comment>Update order_history.status with values from order.status, where order.id = order_history.order_id</comment>
    <update tableName="order_history">
        <column name="status" valueComputed="SELECT o.status FROM order o WHERE o.id = order_id"/>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

If these tables are not connected, then you may use `defaultValueComputed` when you're adding a new column:

```
    <addColumn tableName="order_history">
        <column name="status" type="varchar(255)" defaultValueComputed="some SQL query here"/>
    </addColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks @htshame. By the way, I do not see any necessity for the foreign-key relationship for the first code snippet to work. 
Correct me if I am wrong and let me know how the first code snippet is restricted to tables with foreign-key relation.

Comment: You’re right, it’s just for the sake of consistency